# Filter collection's elements

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Topic` with list of `Comment`:

```
public Optional<Topic> getTopic() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(new Topic(Collections.singletonList(new Comment("comment1"))));
}

public class Topic {

    private List<Comment> comments;

    public Topic(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

}

public class Comment {

    private String name;

    public Comment(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

I want to call `getTopic`, then fetch comments from it with `map` and filter entries of the list like this:

```
getTopic()
    .map(Topic::getComments)
    .filter(comment -> "comment1".equals(comment.getName())); //doesn't work
```

It doesn't work, because in `filter` I have comments, not a single comment. How can I receive new list after filter comments with lambdas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Optional<Topic> topic = getTopic();
if (topic.isPresent()) {
    List<Comment> comments = topic.get().getComments()
        .stream()
        .filter(comment -> "comment1".equals(comment.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You should not call `Optional.get()` unconditionally. Usually, there is a reason for returning an `Optional` from a method.

Comment: @Holger, improved!

Comment: I’d use `List<Comment> result = getTopic() .map(Topic::getComments) .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) .stream() .filter(comment -> "comment1".equals(comment.getName())) .collect(toList());`

Comment: As I understood, there is no convenient way to do this. I will use @Holger's version.

Comment: Instead of `getTopic() .map(Topic::getComments) .orElse(Collections.emptyList()) .stream()` you could also use `getTopic() .map(t -> t.getComments().stream()) .orElseGet(Stream::empty)`

Comment: @Holger That should be an answer.